# How are these conditions able to find a peak number?

Tags: ruby

Need insight on this code. I have the solution but do  not understand it.
The goal here was to create a method that:

- accepts an array of numbers as an arg
- should return an array containing all peaks of array
- an element is considered a peak if it is greater than its left & right neighbor
- first/ last element is considered peak if it is greater than its one neighbor

```rb
def peak_finder(arr)
    peaks = []  
    
    arr.each_index do |i| 
        left = arr[i - 1] # left most num
        mid = arr[i]      # mid num
        right = arr[i + 1]# right most num
        
        if i == 0 && mid > right
            peaks << mid
        elsif i == arr.length - 1 && mid > left
            peaks << mid
        elsif !left.nil? && !right.nil? && mid > right && mid > left  #do not understand this condition
            peaks << mid
        end 
    end
      
    peaks
end 

p peak_finder([1, 3, 5, 4])         
# => [5]
```

Comment: `!left.nil?` check appears to be useless. `left` will never contain nil, if the array doesn't contain nils.

Comment: Not sure what is unclear about that condition. It says, translated literally, "if there are both left and right numbers and the middle number is greater than each of them"

Comment: Work through the condition from left to right. What part doesn't make sense?

Comment: Small, unrelated suggestion - look up `each_cons` method

Answer (score 1):

`!left.nil?` is always `true` so it may be removed. `!right.nil?`, because of where in the `if` statement it is executed, is also always `true`, so it may be removed. One can only speculate as to what was in the mind of the coder when those conditions were stipulated<sup>1</sup>.

Defining `left = arr[i-1]` when `i = 0` and `right = arr[i+1]` when `i = arr.size-1` do no harm (as they are not referenced in the following `if` statement), but that construct is misleading to the reader (and is ugly), so it should be avoided.

One problem with the code is that it fails if the array contains zero or one element.

The code could be corrected and improved as follows.

```
def peak_finder(arr)
  return arr if arr.size < 2
  arr.each_index.filter_map do |i|
    x = arr[i]
    x if
    case i
    when 0
      x > arr[i+1]
    when arr.size-1
      x > arr[i-1]
    else
      x > arr[i-1] && x > arr[i+1]
    end
  end  
end
```

```
peaks([1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6])
  #=> [3, 5, 6]
peaks([1])
  #=> [1]
peaks([])
  #=> []
```

See [Enumerable#filter_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-filter_map), which made its debut in Ruby v2.7.

---

Another way is to make use of the method [Enumerable#each_cons](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons).

```
def peaks(arr)
  [-Float::INFINITY, *arr, -Float::INFINITY].
    each_cons(3).filter_map { |n1,n2,n3| n2 if (n2 > n1 && n2 > n3) }
end
```

```
peaks([1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6])
  #=> [3, 5, 6]
peaks([1])
  #=> [1]
peaks([])
  #=> []
```

<sup>1. Could the coder have forgotten that `i = 0` and `i = arr.size -1` have been dealt with earlier in the `if` statement and was thinking that `arr[i+1]` equals `nil` when `i = arr.size-1` and that `arr[i-1]` equals `nil` when `i = 0` (which is of course incorrect, as `arr[-1]` equals the last last element of the array)?</sup>

Comment: Tastes differ, but a variant which I think is more readable would be to replace `with_object...` with `select { |triplet| triplet.max == triplet[1] }.map { |triplet| triplet[1] }`.

Comment: @pjs, I prefer `with_object` because it requires a single pass through the array and avoids the creation of a temporary array.

Comment: I was under the impression that `with_object` also creates a temporary array, but I'll take your word on it.

Comment: @pjs, `with_object` creates the array that is returned by the method so I would not regard it as a temporary array. As you know, with the variant you suggest `select` creates a temporary array and `map` creates the array that is returned.

Comment: You're correct.  I also just noticed that my use of `max` would yield incorrect results if the max of the triplet is not unique, since an element isn't a peak unless it's strictly greater than its neighbors.

Comment: Readers: if you are wondering why I have two downvotes at the time of writing, I can tell you that they were richly deserved: I penned my original answer--which only gave the method using `each_cons`--on my phone without testing. It was repleat with errors. The second downvote came after I corrected that code, possibly because I had not (yet) directly answered the question, which certainly is a legit reason.

Comment: As of ruby > 2.7 your second example can be cleaned up using one of my favorite new methods `Enumerable#filter_map` but you also brought up a good point in your comment which is: "Can a plateau also be a peak?"

Comment: I've edited my answer to incorporate @engineersmnky's excellent suggestion to use the method `Enumerable#filter_map`.